# Overfull \hbox from printindex

Tags: line-breaking, indexing

I've got a `index` generated with `makeindex` but when compiling the file again, when the index is generated, I get a bunch of overfull `\hbox`.

This is an example of an index that results in overfull:

```
\begin{theindex}
  \item Type, 149, 155
    \subitem GetProperties(), 127, 130, 135, 150
\end{theindex}
```

I don't want to change the .ind-file manually, I'm guessing that is the wrong approach; so what should I do here?

I think that adding a `\newline` before 127 above would work, but as I said, I don't want to change this file directy.

**Edit - Reproducing the error**

Here is a sample to re-produce the error that I am getting, first you need the page "[CreateSpace](https://github.com/aginiewicz/createspace)".

Then I am using this code to generate the file:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[size=novel,trim=0,paper=white,preview=false,gutter=0.5in,inner=0.25in,outer=0.25in,top=0.75in,bottom=0.75in,geometryextra={twoside,heightrounded,truedimen},colourpackage=xcolor,colorpackage=xcolor]{createspace}

\usepackage{index}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{courier}

\makeatother
\makeindex
\begin{document}

\index{A}
\index{B}
\index{C}
\index{D}
\index{E}
\index{F}
\index{G}
\index{H}
\index{I}
\index{J}
\index{K}
\index{L}
\index{M}
\index{N}
\index{O}
\index{P}
\index{T}
\index{U}
\index{V}
\index{X}
\index{Y}
\index{A1}
\index{B2}
\index{C3}
\index{D4}
\index{E5}
\index{F6}
\index{G7}
\index{H8}
\index{I9}
\index{J10}
\index{K11}
\index{L12}
\index{M13}
\index{N14}
\index{O15}
\index{P16}
\index{T20}
\index{U21}
\index{V22}
\index{X23}
\index{Y24}

\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\index{Type!GetProperties()}
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\index{Type!GetProperties()}
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\index{Type!GetProperties()}
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\index{Type!GetProperties()}
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\index{Type!GetProperties()}
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]
\index{Type}
\index{Type!GetProperties()}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

After that I run: `makeindex -s headings.ist MWE.idx`

headings.ist contains the following:

```
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "\\textbf\{\\large "
heading_suffix "\}"
```

If you now go to the end of the generated PDF, you will see that the index is out of the page margins:

[image]

Comment: Would you please try and get a MWE so that we can play with it?

Comment: @egreg, That's the only code that I got. Don't know how to put together a MWE on this.

Comment: Write a document with a couple of `\index` commands. What's needed are the class, the pagination parameters and the way you set the index.

Comment: @egreg, It's not really that simple, the "MWE" will be quite big. Because the indexes most likely need to be in the right hand column to reproduce the error.

Comment: @egreg, Updated with instructions on how to reproduce this. I just want to note also, that by manually editing the `ind`-file and adding `\newline`, the error goes away, but it feels like I'm doing something wrong when I need to manualy edit an auto-generated file like that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can first try relaxing the space parameters in the index:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto{\theindex}{\spaceskip=.33333em plus .33333em minus .11111em }
```

This will allow the interword space to stretch a bit more (the usual stretching value is .22222em).

A different strategy might be

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto{\theindex}{\emergencystretch=6em }
```

which should result in a similar result.

The more drastic

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto{\theindex}{\sloppy}
```

is definitely not recommended.

Comment: I'm using the exact code in the MWE, but I added the two lines that you mentioned. It's printed on the first page. See my code here to verify: http://privatepaste.com/8f584a2b96/latex and here is a screenshot of that page https://dl.dropbox.com/u/62721809/MWE_pdf.png

Comment: it seems like it works on the lipsum MWE, but not when I moved it to the real book. Maybe I need to experiment with the numbers a bit.

Comment: Thanks  by the way. Also, is this really recommended too do?

Comment: @FilipEkberg Yes, of course; the index doesn't need so strict bounds on paragraphs as regular text. The ragged right typesetting suggested by Kurt should be considered too.

Comment: Awesome! I still consider myself a LaTeX newbie, writing my first book with it. :) Thanks for all the help, I'll wait a couple of days before accepting an answer, want to see if Kurt adds a MWE that I can compare with. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

An Index needs no justification. With the package `ragged2e` you can use the macro `\RaggedRight` to get a left-justified index. The ancillary effect of this: no overfull `\hbox`.

For example:

```
\documentclass[%
  a5paper      % papersize
 ,draft        % to show the overfull hbox
]{article}

\usepackage{index,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage{ragged2e}   % ragged margin with hyphenation
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\index{Type!GetProperties()}\clearpage\lipsum[1]\clearpage
\lipsum[1]\index{Type!GetProperties()}\clearpage\lipsum[1]\clearpage
\lipsum[1]\index{Type!GetProperties()}\clearpage\lipsum[1]\clearpage
\lipsum[1]\index{Type!GetProperties()}\clearpage\lipsum[1]\clearpage
\lipsum[1]\index{Type!GetProperties()}\clearpage\lipsum[1]\clearpage
\lipsum[1]\index{Type!GetProperties()}\clearpage\lipsum[1]\clearpage
\lipsum[1]\index{Type!GetProperties()}\clearpage
\index{Type}\index{Test}\index{Type!GetProperties()}

{              % start group
%\RaggedRight  % left-justified setting    % line 21
\printindex    % insert index here
}              % end group
\end{document}
```

You will get the warning "overfull hbox". With the class option `draft` the overfull box is marked with an black box. Delete the leading comment in line 21 and the warning disappears ...

My used index file is:

```
\begin{theindex}
{\bfseries\hfil T\hfil}\nopagebreak

  \item Test, 14
  \item Type, 14
    \subitem GetProperties(), 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 14

\end{theindex}
```

My used `ist` file is:

```
% Index-Stildatei 
headings_flag    1  % Big letter before group
heading_prefix   "{\\bfseries\\hfil "
heading_suffix   "\\hfil}\\nopagebreak\n"
symhead_positive "Symbole"

delim_0  
delim_1  
delim_2
```